# What is the best practice SQLite + RxJava?

Tags: android, sqlite, rx-java, mvp

I really interested to apply many best practice to my application.
Right now, I am developing an application which is fetching item from SQLite.
I'm trying to use RxJava, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

This is my code for making observable :
DataManager.java

```
public Observable<Cursor> fetchData(String a, String b) {
    String query = "select * from " + TABLE_TEST +
            " where ... + a && b ";

    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    c.moveToFirst();

    return Observable.just(c);
}
```

and this is the function that call above code :
PresenterDb.java

```
void fetchSchedulesDb(String channelReq, String dateReq){
    unSubscribeAll();
    subscribe(getCursor(channelReq, dateReq), PresenterDb.this);
}
```

and this is the subscribe function :
BasePresenterDb.java

```
protected <R> void subscribe(Observable<R> observable, Observer<R> observer){
    Subscription subscription = observable
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribe(observer);
    configureSubscription().add(subscription);
}
```

PresenterDb.java class implements Observer so in this class there is onCompleted, onError, and onNext.

I doubt it's not the best practice because I think the getCursor still running in main thread, not in the background.
If so, how can I get the cursor in background thread.
Thank you.

Comment: I think best practice is using Observable to return objects of your query as data model instead of curser!

Answer (score 4):

You would be better off using a library like [SQLBrite](https://github.com/square/sqlbrite) or [StorIO](https://github.com/pushtorefresh/storio) rather than implementing your own solution.

Answer (score 0):

Room is indeed a good choice.

[Save data in a local database using Room](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/)